# tty1 on monitor A; tty2 on monitor B

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, tty

This is an odd question and I don't think I would even have a use for it, but;

Can I bring up `tty1` on one monitor and `tty2` on the other, both at the same time?

Comment: Very good question. Traditional unix terminal were a workstation with one monitor or teletype, so one can assume it's impossible to make two output devices. However it's  been years since that time, so perhaps someone has figured it out. This question needs more attention from the community

Comment: Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556782/tty-dual-monitors

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  You can use a terminal and then in each terminal use this command.

monitor 1 terminal

```
screen /dev/tty1
```

monitor 2 terminal

```
screen /dev/tty2
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. I mean the ctrl + alt + f1 terminal...

Comment: In that case I don't believe this is possible.  You could potentially stretch your resolution over the two monitors and then use a terminal multiplexer such as tmux to get the desired effect though.

Comment: Maybe using multi-seats? But that requires 2 monitors, 2 mice, 2 keyboards... probably not what you are looking for. Although with Symergy, maybe it's possible to use just one keyboard/mouse and share between screens...

Comment: I don't quite understand this answer. What do you expect to achieve with `screen /dev/tty1`?